# how can i change this SQL to Django ORM code? (group by)

Tags: sql, django, orm

I need to retrieve the **Process element (by maximum processid) per unique serial number.**

I'm using mysql and this is my django model.

```py
class Sample(models.Model):
    processid = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
    serialnumber = models.CharField(max_length=256)  ##
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

class Process(models.Model):
    sample = models.ForeignKey(Sample, blank=False, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

And this is sql query what i need to change to django.

```sql
SELECT process.*
FROM process
WHERE process.id in (
    SELECT max(sample.processid) as max_processid
    from sample
    group by sample.serialnumber
);
```

This is Process table. 
[image]

And This is Sample table.
[image]

**Self Answer**

```py
    subquery = Subquery(Sample.objects.filter(
        serialnumber = OuterRef('sample__serialnumber')
    ).order_by(
        '-processid'
    ).values(
        'id'
    )[:1])

    filtered_process_queryset = Process.objects.filter(id=subquery)
```

Comment: It is not necessary to convert sql to a django orm you can just use raw sql query you can read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/ for more information.

Comment: Thanks but I need to modify the result Queryset....

Comment: Thanks for replying but id is correct. because, i want to compare the processid retrieved by subquery.

But i modified the sql with table name, to be more accurately.